# Python MIME email attachment sending method sends jpg files as "noname.eml" instead

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I use MIME and SMTPLIB instead of sending my attachment "random.jpg" it sends "noname.eml" which is unopenable and unseeable, I am unable to send attachments correctly for this reason. Why is this caused and how can I solve it?

I tried to change the extension from "png" to "jpg" but the issue pursues.

```
fromaddr1 = ""
toaddr1 = ""
accpass1 = ""

msg1 = MIMEMultipart()

msg1['From'] = fromaddr1
msg1['To'] = toaddr1
msg1['Subject'] = "YOUR COMPUTER HAS BEEN ACCESSED"

body1 = "Someone has gained access to your computer"

msg1.attach(MIMEText(body1, 'plain'))

filename1 = "random.jpg" 
attachment1 = open("random.jpg","rb")

part1 = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part1.set_payload((attachment1).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part1)
part1.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment1; filename1= %s" % 
filename1)

msg1.attach(part1)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr1, accpass1)
text = msg1.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr1, toaddr1, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: `part1.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment1; filename1=%s" % 
filename1)` => `part1.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment1; filename=%s" % 
filename1)`.

Comment: @PhilipTzou What did you mean?

Comment: In the second parameter of `add_header()`, change `attachment1` and `filename1` to `attachment` and `filename`.

Comment: @PhilipTzou Thank you so much!!! This fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

in header:

```
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
```

instead attachment:

```
with open(PATH_TO_ZIP_FILE,'rb') as file:
    msg.attach(MIMEApplication(file.read(), Name='filename.zip'))
```